# Use deserialize data into Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I used a deserializer in order to read data from an API, and now I would like to use this data into Excel. The deserializer stored the data as in the screen below.

[Screen of the data stored by the deserializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A4nU.png)

I would like to access this data easily so :

**What is the best way to use retrieve this data to paste it in columns into Excel ?**

I already tried many things (loops) but it takes too much time, to retrieve each parameters (cloudcover, humidity,tempC...)

Many thanks.

Comment: what kind of file is the data in?  XML? Why not read the data directory from the API into Excel?

Comment: It is a JSON file, Im open to every new idea :)

Comment: What kind of API is this? How are you currently connecting to it?  Why was a deserializer necessary?

Comment: It's the API of World Weather Online : https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/code-examples.aspx

Comment: you just need this data into Excel?  Excel can pull directly from an API like that.  `Data` > `From Web`